# Notification closed when Service finished

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, android-intentservice

I'm creating a notification and updating it during the execution of an intent service. The problem appears when the services finished, also the notification is canceled.

```
intentNotification = new Intent(this, ScanProcessActivity.class);
    intentNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_app)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

What can I do to preserve the notification after the Intent Service is finished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use a NotificationManager to display the notification?

Comment: yes, I'm using notification manager to show the notification.

Comment: `setAutoCancel(boolean autoCancel)` Added in API level 11 Make this notification automatically dismissed when the user touches it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found a solution.

The main problem was that I was using:

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

which cause unexpected behaviour such as cancel notification when thread is finished.

The solution was to change the startForeground() call to:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```